# Bootstrap navbar with 2 brands to the left and right with centered links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a navbar that looks like:

[BRAND1] ... [LINK1 | LINK2 | LINK3] ... [BRAND2]

this is what I get, but the collapsed menu looks weird and is missing the border between the navbar and the collapsed menu. http://www.bootply.com/fp8e8IYGuj

I'm happy with the look and behavior when the width is > than 768px, but not the collapsed look and behavior. I want it to behave like a "normal" collapsed menu. For example this one:
http://www.bootply.com/GDf0pzFK9b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `clear` the floated elements, add this on your CSS:

```
/* navbar menu when collapsed */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
     clear:both;
  }
}
```

Check **[TheDemo](http://www.bootply.com/uuM3LX0i3o)**

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason cant change the CSS like @Danko suggests then you could stick with the bootstrap classes provided and just duplicate brand2 element for mobile and desktop.

The `hidden-*` css classes within bootstrap allow you to do this with no additional CSS markup.

```
<div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">BRAND1</a>

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand pull-right hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">BRAND23</a>
    </div>

  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand pull-right hidden-xs">BRAND2</a>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Example at http://www.bootply.com/Qf9w7wNK6t

You can read more on the Bootstrap Docs - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Personally I would use the `clear:both` method suggested.